# MySQL 8.0 Reference says MOD() + 1 returns different result from 1 + MOD()

Tags: mysql, documentation

I am trying to learn MySQL reading Official MySQL 8.0 reference/tutorial. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html

In the paragraph that explains how you get the January using calculation, it says

> A different way to accomplish the same task is to add 1 to get the
>   next month after the current one after using the modulo function (MOD)
>   to wrap the month value to 0 if it is currently 12:

`mysql> SELECT name, birth FROM pet
WHERE MONTH(birth) = MOD(MONTH(CURDATE()), 12) + 1;`

> MONTH() returns a number between 1 and 12. And MOD(something,12)
>   returns a number between 0 and 11. So the addition has to be after the
>   MOD(), otherwise we would go from November (11) to January (1).

My question is why the addition should be after MOD()? 
I get the same result even if the addition is before 'MOD(MONTH(CURDATE()), 12)' as below.

`mysql> SELECT name, birth FROM pet
WHERE MONTH(birth) = 1 + MOD(MONTH(CURDATE()), 12);`

am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two expressions are identical, because addition is, by definition, commutative:

```
MOD(MONTH(CURDATE()), 12) + 1
1 + MOD(MONTH(CURDATE()), 12)
```

The logic of why either of these works is that when the month of the current date, which is a number between 1 and 12, be 11 or less, the modulus by 12 simply returns that number, and we add one month to it.  In the case of a December month (12), the expression 12 % 12 returns 0, and then we add one to obtain January (1).

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: Ah, Thank you. I understood now.